# embedded linux/QNX - how to completely zero out flash

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, qnx

I have a bug related to persistent files.

To determine the exact sequence of steps to reproduce the bug, I need to start out the flash disk at a known state.

**QUESTION**

Using linux/QNX commands, how do I completely zero out the entire flash disk while being Telnet'd into the system?

Comment: Writing zeroes to flash is a bad idea; you're wasting a write/erase cycle.  The erased state of all ones is more sensible.  Use `mtd-utils`, e.g. flash_erase or flash_eraseall, and then create a fresh filesystem.  BTW you're probably asking an XY question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **QNX**, you can try the [**`flashctl` tool**](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities%2Ftopic%2Ff%2Fflashctl.html) to erase the entire flash.

To erase the entire flash, run:

```
flashctl -p /dev/fs0 -e
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be better](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks @anonymous2. Updated the answer.